# How to stop the functions of first form when second form is open in C#.net

Tags: c#

I am new to programming. Apologize in advance

I am using Speak function. When first form is hide, and second form is open. Speak function is still works. I want to stop that function. How i can do this

```
  //Second Form      
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }
     //Speak Button 
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {         
        sSynth.Dispose();
        if (textBox1.Text != "") //if text area is not empty
        {
            sSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            sSynth.SpeakAsync(textBox1.Text);
            sSynth.SpeakCompleted+=new
          EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs(reader_SpeakCompleted);
        }
    }
    private void reader_SpeakCompleted(object sender,                           SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel all background async speech there is a jolly good *cancel* method that you should call from 1st form:

```
sSynth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll ();
```

> Cancels all queued, asynchronous, speech synthesis operations

...or to cancel a *specific* prompt use this one:

```
sSynth.SpeakAsyncCancel (_prompt);
```

...where `_prompt` is the return value from your prior `sSynth.SpeakAsync(...)` which should look something like this:

```
_prompt = sSynth.SpeakAsync(something);
```

### More

- *[SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall(v=vs.110).aspx)*